# How to get the count of # data rows in .csv file in R using nrow() function

Tags: r

I have a data file (data.csv file) in my working directory. The first row of my file has column names. I want to count all the rows in my .csv file (excluding the first row) using the nrow() function. Size of the file is 4kb on disk, otherwise 2.83 kb
Thanks
Jyoti

Comment: In case you are not sure whether it is a vector or data.frame, use `NROW`

Comment: Do your want count without reading the data to R? In Linux and Unix one can use `wc` from the operating system.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the number of lines of a given file without loading it in memory, you'll have to get it using command line. wc -l followed by the fine name works for both linux/unix and windows and can be executed in R :

```
as.integer(unlist(strsplit(system(paste0("wc -l ", file_name), intern=T), " "))[1])
```